# Pourquoi prononce-t-on différemment le mot "huit" dans certaines régions ?

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, accents-régionaux

En français, le mot "huit", lorsqu'il est employé seul, est normalement prononcé `[ɥit]`.

Cependant, j'ai remarqué que dans certaines régions (personnellement, j'ai remarqué ça en région parisienne), les locuteurs ajoutaient parfois le son `[l]` au début du mot. On obtient alors `[lɥit]`.

J'ai trouvé [très peu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Discussion_Projet:Prononciation_(2005)) [d'informations](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire:Questions_sur_les_mots/f%C3%A9vrier_2013) sur cette prononciation. [Voici un exemple](https://www.france.tv/sport/tennis/roland-garros/2021803-d-schwartzman-arg-12-vs-r-nadal-esp-2-1-2-finale-court-philippe-chatrier.html) (celui qui m'a fait poser cette question). À 55min45, la commentatrice prononce clairement le chiffre 8 de cette façon. Je reste preneur d'éventuels extraits à ajouter dans ce post, car cette rediffusion d'un match de tennis ne sera peut-être pas disponible de façon permanente.

Ma question est la suivante : **comment et pourquoi est-on arrivé à cette prononciation dans certaines régions** (et chez certains individus en particulier) ? Y a-t-il une ancienne structure de laquelle pourrait dériver cette construction ?

Comment: Est-ce qu'ils disent aussi *l'un* et *l'onze* ?

Comment: Pas que je sache. A priori, ce serait plutôt dérivé du son [ɥi] plutôt que des nombres en eux-mêmes. Je précise quand même que j'ai entendu cette prononciation venant de personnes que je ne connais pas énormément, donc il m'est difficile d'analyser leur façon de parler.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu ce régionalisme par contre huit fait partie des mots en 'ui' qui sont prononcés différemment dans certains régions, notamment en Belgique francophone ([wit] en l'occurence).

Comment: lived 10 years in Paris, never heard it, honest. On the other hand, like the comment above me, I can vouch that in my native country (Lebanon) it's pronounced _[wit]_.

Comment: J'ai ajouté un exemple dans ma question. Ce n'était pas la première fois que j'entendais cette prononciation, mais c'est à ce moment-là que j'ai eu l'idée de poser cette question.

Comment: C'est indéniable, on entend bien [lɥit] dans cet extrait. J'avoue que je n'y aurais pas fait attention sans une écoute attentive. Je crois que la commentatrice est Constance Sénac de Montsembernard, originaire de Normandie. Il faudrait peut-être demander l'avis d'un orthophoniste...

Comment: https://forvo.com/word/dix-huit/#fr Ecoutez la différence entre un français et un canadien, par exemple.

Comment: @Lambie En quoi ce serait pertinent ? Que ce [soit](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/huit#Prononciation) \wit\, \ɥɪt\ ou \ʏ.ɪt\, la question parle d'un « son [l] au début du mot » avant ces nuances et le locuteur est originaire de Normandie.

Comment: I think I figured out what is going on here. The number 8 in French is le huit. The l sound comes from that: [lɥit]. This has a name in linguistics and I can't remember what it is. books.google.com/… So, it is not a pronunciation per se, it's an elision.

Answer (score 6):

Bravo et merci à l'auteur de ce post, pour ce sujet si spécifique qui m'intrigue depuis des années.

Je suis professeur de soutien scolaire et j'accompagne les élèves en maths et physique en cours particuliers. J'exerce dans le sud de la France et mes élèves ont le plus souvent l'accent méridional. Mais bien d'autres accents sont également représentés.

Le fait de les écouter attentivement et individuellement lorsque nous travaillons ensemble me conduit à repérer des éléments de prononciation, de dialectes, de sociolectes et même de chronolectes (quand je parle avec leurs parents et grands-parents) qui m'interpellent, sans que je n'ose jamais m'enquérir de leur région d'origine.

La première fois que j'ai entendu prononcer [lɥit] pour "8", c'était auprès d'un de mes élèves qui souffre de dysphasie, je n'ai donc pas réalisé qu'il pouvait s'agir d'une prononciation répandue. Puis, au fil des rencontres, 3-4 de mes élèves m'ont fait cette troublante surprise de prononcer le chiffre "8" avec la forme [lɥit]. J'ai alors compris que c'était une variante dialectale.

Il y a très longtemps, j'ai étudié le néerlandais, langue dans laquelle 8 se dit "acht", (prononcé et écrit comme en allemand, notamment). J'utilisais une méthode sur laquelle, à la page enseignant les nombres, pour "80", il était écrit "tachtig", alors que "8" et "18" donnent respectivement "acht" et "achtien". Sans être linguiste et sans prendre la peine de chercher dans google, ce "t" en trop me fait penser à "het", article défini du néerlandais, un peu comme si c'était "het achtig", "Le 80". Un peu comme dans "la Relation de van 't Hoff", (nom d'une loi de thermodynamique), dont le nom du découvreur est un toponyme, contracté de "Van het Hoff", avec cet étrange t apostrophe en vrac.

Comment: Dans notre langue(Persian) 8 est prononce hasht too(avec prononciation anglais)

Comment: Le t de tachtig est évocateur de l'article neutre, mais n'a probablement rien à voir avec ce dernier. L'étymologie habituelle est qu'il vient d'un ancien préfixe, dérivé de hund (100, comme dans hundred and honderd) qui permettait de former les dizaines de 70 à 120 dans les langues du Nord de la Germanie (vieil anglais hundendleftiġ "hundeleventy", or 110). En néerlandais, le suffixe s'est réduit à t- dans 80 et est l'explication pour la prononciation avec un /s/ initial de zeventig (70)

Comment: [lɥit] pour "8", parce qu'il s'agit de le + huit. le huit. Ce n'est pas une variante dialectal. C'est un phenomène linguistique.

Answer (score 2):

Le projet PFC (Phonologie du Français Contemporain) recense les parlers francophones des différentes régions. Bien que le [site web](https://www.projet-pfc.net/) soit très orienté vers la documentation des faits de liaison et de prononciation des schwas, il permet de chercher les [occurrences de 8](https://public.projet-pfc.net/transcription/?q=huit#results) et d'écouter leurs prononciations.

Je ne crois pas que [lɥit] fasse partie des données collectées.

Par ailleurs, dans l'exemple du match de tennis, la présence du [l] n'est pas particulièrement claire. On pourrait aussi transcrire :

- plus de huit coups => plydəʔɥiku

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord avec l'interprétation selon laquelle on distinguerait le son `[ʔ]`. Pour moi, il est clair qu'on n'entend pas de coup de glotte dans cet exemple. D'ailleurs, si c'était le cas, je pense que la prononciation serait bien moins fluide que ce qu'on entend de la part de la commentatrice.

Comment: Les français et les canadiens prononcent huit et suite de manière différente.

Comment: @Lambie En quoi ce serait pertinent ? Que ce [soit](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/huit#Prononciation) \wit\, \ɥɪt\ ou \ʏ.ɪt\, la question parle d'un « son [l] au début du mot » avant ces nuances et le locuteur est originaire de Normandie.

Answer (score 1):

Je suis parisienne, et ma prononciation est clairement [lɥit], et la plupart des personnes que je fréquente le font aussi. Mais c'est vrai que je ne trouve nulle part d'information là-dessus, alors qu'on parle beaucoup plus régulièrement d'autres points de l'accent parisien qui me sont pour le coup complètement étrangers (le fameux e prépausal par exemple, ou le [ç] après un /i/ en fin de mot). Ça me paraît pas improbable que ça soit une évolution récente et pas trop répandue. Dans les faits [lɥit] et [ɥit] sont suffisamment semblables pour que la plupart des gens ne s'en rendent même pas compte, surtout dans le flot d'une conversation (on ne m'a par exemple jamais fait la remarque comme quoi je prononçais mal). C'est possible que ça soit une espèce de réflexe pour briser des hiatus, étant donné que huit est le seul mot en [ɥi] qui peut suivre une voyelle (à ma connaissance, huile par exemple est systématiquement précédé d'un déterminant, et les autres sont de toutes façons rares et plus utilisés). Par exemple "il en a huit" /ilãnaɥit/ j'ai naturellement tendance à caler un /l/ pour fluidifier la phrase.

Comment: Ça arrive aussi avec [huile](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompe_%C3%A0_huile).

Answer (score -1):

Il semblerait que cet usage soit très restreint étant donné que dans la recherche suivante, qui est très avancée, toutes les variantes principales ont été enregistrées. On peut voir par exemple qu'en Normandie seule, quatre variantes ont été reconnues. Comment se ferait-il que la variante en question ([lɥit]) dans la région parisienne aurait échappé aux investigations ? C'est très vraisemblablement qu'elle n'est partagée que par un infime nombre de locuteurs.

[Sound Comparisons](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Romance/map/eight/Lgs_All)

*Addition subséquente à la fourniture du seul échantillon disponible*

Après une écoute du nouvel échantillon je tends à croire que cette personne a  désespérémment fouillé son esprit à la recherche d'une nouvelle forme, encore inexistante. Si on examine les mots de cette commentatrice on s'aperçoit qu'elle dit exactement ceci.

*On est tout de même partis sur euh… une moyenne d'échange à la…plus de l'huit coups*

Le fait que la préposition « à » précède le son « la » et que après « plus » on trouve « l' » tend fortement à laisser penser qu'il s'agit de l'article « la » pour le son « la » et de l'article « le » pour le « l' », article dont le « e » a été élidé selon la prononciation coutumière des parisiens. Le fait que la commentatrice s'engage sur la forme « à la » est très probablement le résultat d'une impression qu'une expression toute faite  existerait pour qualifier un échange  de huit coups ou qu'une construction standard peut se faire en commençant ainsi  (« à la ») avant de s'apercevoir qu'elle a fait fausse route, d'où l'hésitation et un essai de rattrapage avec « plus de » en espérant  encore qu'un terme qui convienne syntaxiquement lui vienne à l'esprit mais cela n'arrive pas assez vite et elle se sort d'embarras en énonçant l'essentiel, c'est à dire « le huit coups », « le » étant une tentative de minimiser le manque de correction de sa formulation, peut-être parce que « coup » est masculin, mais cette dernière supposition est moins sure.

Les formes trouvées dans ce lapsus se retrouvent dans des termes possibles afférents au contexte (au moins **du** huit coups à tous les échange… un échange **à** huit coup), termes qui n'ont pas à être utilisés dans les milieux du tennis mais dont le modèle a un impact certain sur le locuteur du fait de sa générale application dans le langage.

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question. Ce ne devrait être au mieux qu'un commentaire.

Comment: @jlliagre Ça répond à la question en cela qu'un usage qui est très restreint ne laisse pas de traces et que les linguistes n'ayant pas le temps de s'intéresser à un usage local qui ne dépasse pas le nombre de quelques centaines, il n'y a aucune chance d'obtenir des informations. On voit dans cette source très minutieuse que de menues différences ont été enregistrées en Normandie; ce ne peut être que parce qu'elles représentaient chacune une assez grande population. Si ce l n'est pas reconnu à Paris il ne peut pas avoir une bien grande représentation.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que tu as autorité pour décider de ce qui peut intéresser ou non un linguiste. D'autre part, contrairement à ce que tu écris, le site dont tu fournis un lien n'a pas grand chose à voir avec la question posée. Ce qu'il présente, ce ne sont pas des prononciations du français avec des accents régionaux mais, en dehors de Paris, des prononciations de mots traduits en quelques dialectes ou langues régionales. Il ne mentionne par exemple même pas le *wit* belge qui est pourtant la variante de prononciation du mot huit  la plus connue.

Comment: Le seul accent régional français représenté est celui de Perpignan.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne prétend pas du tout avoir autorité pour décider de ce qui peut intéresser un linguiste; j'avance seulement comme une raison très plausible qu'étant donné le nombre important des contextes linguistiques à étudier un linguiste choisira plutôt ceux qui ont le plus de substance. Par exemple, j'ai entendu dans la région Bordelaise quelques personnes de très peu d'éducation qui plus ou moins régulièrement prononçaient "putain" comme "puteille"; ces gens-là étaient une exception. J'estime qu'il y a peu de chance qu'un linguiste fasse des recherches approfondies sur quelque (1/2)

Comment: @jlliagre chose comme cela, qui, très probablement résulte d'une déformation très localisée et qui n'a peut-être pas même de racines profondes. L'accent qui figure pour la région parisienne n'est-il pas "régional ? (2/2)

Comment: Oui, bien sûr, l'accent parisien est aussi un accent régional mais pourquoi persistes-tu à appuyer ta réponse sur des données qui ne concernent pas la prononciation du français ? Une seule manière de prononcer *huit* en français est rapportée dans cette page. En particulier, les quatre variantes dont tu parles on été prononcées par des locuteurs qui s'exprimaient en [normand](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normand), une langue en sérieux danger.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne tiens pas spécialement à ma réponse et ne désire pas non plus enterrer le sujet du l devant le huit ; si la possibilité que j'émets est propre  à décourager la recherche elle n'a rien d'un dictat ; il est clair que quiconque a du temps à engouffrer dans une telle question et veut  faire cela le peut ; je dis seulement que de tels efforts pourraient bien se révéler improductifs, même qu'il n'existe pas encore une science du langage qui cerne son usage avec un tel souci du détail.

Comment: Tu es libre d'avoir cette opinion mais tu ne semble pas avoir compris que dans ta réponse, tu l'appuie sur des données *irrelevantes*, comme on dit en anglais.

Comment: @jlliagre Vous m'apprenez qu'elles ne sont pas aussi approfondies qu'on pourrait le penser, je veux bien croire cela.

Comment: Je n'ai pas dit qu'elles n'étaient pas approfondies mais qu'elles sont essentiellement hors-sujet par rapport à la question posée qui concerne des personnes s'exprimant en français actuel. Tu ignores peut-être que d'autres langues que le français ont été parlées et sont encore quelquefois parlées sur le territoire français (Héritiers de la langue d'oïl comme le normand, le picard, le gallo, le berrichon, etc. ou non comme l'occitan, le breton, le corse, le catalan, l'alsacien, l'arpitan, etc.) ainsi que dans les autres zones francophones comme la Wallonie, Bruxelles, la Romandie, Québec, etc.

Comment: https://forvo.com/word/dix-huit/#fr And it's not just huit, it's suite too.

Comment: @Lambie En quoi ce serait pertinent ? Que ce [soit](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/huit#Prononciation) \wit\, \ɥɪt\ ou \ʏ.ɪt\, la question parle d'un « son [l] au début du mot » avant ces nuances et le locuteur est originaire de Normandie.

Comment: I  think I figured out what is going on here. There is no pronunciation of huit, an 8, as [lɥit]. That is the pronunciation of **le huit**, spoken fast.  The l sound comes from the le when it is pronounced as one with huit. The pronunciation differences for huit, as for suite or huître are basically Québecois and France metropolitan, which is why I posted the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Le un, le deux, le trois, le quatre, le cinq, le six, le sept, **le huit**.